# Distribution family that is "invariant" under multiplication by a uniform variate

Tags: distributions

For which distribution family $\mathcal F$ do we have

$$X \in \mathcal F \implies XU \in \mathcal F$$

where $U$ is a uniform variate on $[0,1]$ independent of $X$?

Comment: Any motivation or background of this problem?

Comment: @Zhanxiong I don't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

As a potentially  motivating example, consider the log scale. We're now looking to see what family we would leave alone when $\log(U)$ is added.

The log of a uniform is a flipped exponential.

If the variate it was added to was a flipped gamma with the same scale, the result would also be a flipped gamma.

So the original family would be of the form $X=\exp(-Y)$ where $Y$ is a Gamma variate.

Comment: Implicitly you assume $X$ has non-negative support.  A full correct answer is to take *any* family $\mathcal F$ and to consider the collection of distribution classes that contain $\mathcal F$ as well as all $XU$ for $X$ in these classes.  Their intersection answers the question.  It's easy to exhibit various families that result in different intersections, showing there are (far more) than one family with this property.